The sum of two Maurer-Cartan forms is a Maurer-Cartan form
Let $\omega_1, \omega_2$ be two Maurer-Cartan forms, that is 1-forms satisfying the Maurer-Cartan equation
$$d\omega_i+\frac{1}{2}[\omega_i, \omega_i]=0$$
for $i=1, 2$. Then, it seems that $\omega_1+\omega_2$ is a Maurer-Cartan form since
\begin{align*}
d(\omega_1+\omega_2)+\frac{1}{2}[\omega_1+\omega_2, \omega_1+\omega_2]=d\omega_1+d\omega_2+\frac{1}{2}[\omega_1, \omega_1]+\frac{1}{2}[\omega_2, \omega_2]=0,
\end{align*}
where we used $[\omega_1, \omega_2]+[\omega_2, \omega_1]=0$. I could not find a confirmation of this simple fact. Is there an implicit error in the argument?

why is $[\omega_1, \omega_2]+[\omega_2, \omega_1]=0$?

Reminder: $\omega_i$ are $\mathfrak g$-valued, not scalar-valued. Also, isn't there another condition in the definition of a Maurer-Cartan form? The sum will violate that condition quite obviously.

It is not true that $[w_1,w_2]=-[w_2,w_1]$. Since $w_1$ and $w_2$ are 1-forms, one actually has
$$
[w_1,w_2] = -(-1)^{|w_1||w_2|} [w_2,w_1] = [w_2,w_1],
$$
where $|w_i|$ is the degree of $w_i$, namely $1$. Therefore, the bracket commutes on 1-forms. It follows that the Maurer--Cartan equation on the sum has a remainder $[w_1,w_2]$, which need not be zero.
